# OpenPyXL - Insert list contents and go to next row (for loop)

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I'm trying to make a simple spreadsheet:

I input some details, and it gets saved into the spreadsheet.

So, I input the details into 2 lists, and 1 normal variable:

`Dates = ['01/01/14', '01/02/14', '01/03/14']`

`Amount = ['1', '2', '3']`

`Cost = 12` (because it is always the same)

I'm trying to insert these into a spreadsheet like this:

```
for i in range(len(Dates)):
    insertThese.extend([Dates[i], Amount[i], Cost])
ws.append(insertThese)
```

but this adds the 3 things side-by-side like:

```
     A       B  C         D       E  F         G        H  I
01/01/14     1 12        01/02/14 2 12         01/03/14 3 12
```

but I want it to be like, basically adding a new row at the end of `insertThese.expand`...

```
       A       B  C         
01/01/14       1 12  
01/02/14       2 12
01/03/14       3 12
```

I don't understand how to do this without removing by headers at the top of the file.

I tried using `iter_rows()` but that removes the header.

So how do I get the details to be added row-by-row?

I'm new to openpyxl, so if anything's obvious - sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip`/ `itertools.izip` to loop over your lists in parallel. Something like the following:

```
for d, a in zip(Dates, Amount):
    ws.append([d, a, 12])
```

Comment: Error: `TypeError: zip argument #3 must support iteration`

Comment: If this did work, would it add the separate dates on 3 different rows at the end of the sheet? Because that's what I'm trying to achieve...

Comment: It's easy enough to adjust the sequences that you're looping over. I've changed the code to do this. See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip for how to use the zip function.

Comment: Unfortunately the edited code simply add the last date and last amount. Why is this?

Comment: Please help! Could you at least try the code and see if it works for you? Thanks.

Comment: I provided you with all the information to solve the problem and the code runs as expected for me.

I don't think it's the purpose of StackOverflow to write your code for you.

Comment: I'm not asking you to write the code for me, I'm asking you for help in getting the code to work - the code you've given me, just adds the last date and amount rather than all of them. If the code works for you, do you think you know why it isn't working for me? Sorry if you think I'm trying to just get code from you, but I just want help in understanding why it works for you and not me.